# AVG 10 free detects "Input validation exploit"

Tags: support, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's this virus threat on Google Chrome when editing a Stack Overflow post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96326/whats-this-virus-threat-on-google-chrome-when-editing-a-stack-overflow-post)

I just got this while my computer was idling:

> Danger: Surf-Shield has detected active threats on this page and has blocked access for your protection.
>
> URL: stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/javascript
>      Name: IE Input Validation Exploit

I have never got this before; do you have any suggestion on what I should do?

Comment: Just a guess -- [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177583/how-to-open-exe-with-javascript-xpcom-as-windows-run)? Looks like something a simple string matching test might consider suspicious. Does your app get triggered on that page?

Comment: It did not do anything just going to it.
Also I should of said, I am not particularly worried myself, this is more of of tell SE that something might be wrong with there site question then a real question.