# What's this virus threat on Google Chrome when editing a Stack Overflow post?

Tags: discussion, google, javascript, google-chrome, security

When editing my previous post I got this:

[image]

How does it come? It seems it only occurs on this particular post, [Running Exe in Firefox why do I get an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472435/running-exe-in-firefox-why-do-i-get-an-error), not on the one I am writing here for example.

When clicking on info it indicates `chrome.exe`.

How is it possible on a website?

Comment: You have 50 unattended notifications.

Comment: Well, it's 55 now.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93196/avg-10-free-detects-input-validation-exploit (I'm closing the other one, though, because this one has answers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first guess is that `RunExe('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start winword.exe');` looks suspicious to some heuristic since it's similar to strings that occur in exploits.

In addition you have code in there that instantiates an ActiveX object, once again suspicious:

```
MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
```

So I'd say it's just yet another false positive. Anti malware/virus heuristics have those all the time.

Comment: ok thanks I prefer that it is false positive :)

Answer (score 1):

The best idea would be to press the button "More Info" which should detail the "IE Input validation exploit" further. Please note that this is not a Chrome exploit and is detected by your anti-virus.

Comment: I clicked on info and it says chrome.exe

Comment: My question is not even about chrome it is about securing website

Comment: How is your question related to securing a website? Your question is about your overly paranoid antivirus.