# Exploit on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, exploit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AVG 10 free detects “Input validation exploit”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93196/avg-10-free-detects-input-validation-exploit)

**There seems to be an exploit on the Stackoverflow. Is this real?**

[image]

Comment: No. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404857/wordpress-trojan-issue) included some malicious code that a user found on his site as an example. Virus scanners often can't tell that the code is just presented as text, not executed, and they think there's a threat when there isn't. [This has happened many times before.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=virus+avg)